# What is correct solution for this (Benny and Segments) question on Hackerearth?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

How do i correctly solve this question [Benny and Segments](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/sorting/bubble-sort/practice-problems/algorithm/benny-and-segments-marcheasy/). The solution given for this question is not correct . According to editorial for this question, following is a correct solution.

```java
import java.io.*; import java.util.*;
class Pair{
    int a; int b;
    public Pair(int a , int b){ this.a = a; this.b = b;}
}

class TestClass {
    static BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    static StringTokenizer st;
    static void rl() throws Exception{st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());}
    static int pInt() {return Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());}
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        rl();
        int T = pInt();
        while(T-- > 0){
            rl();
            int N = pInt();
            int L = pInt();
            Pair[] p = new Pair[N];
            for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
                rl();
                int l = pInt();
                int r = pInt();
                p[i] = new Pair(l, r);
            }
            Arrays.sort(p, new Comparator<Pair>(){
                @Override
                public int compare(Pair o1, Pair o2)
                {
                    return o1.a - o2.a;
                }
            });
            boolean possible = false;
            for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
                int start = p[i].a;
                int curr_max = p[i].b;
                int req_max = p[i].a + L;
                for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){
                    if(p[i].a <= p[j].a &&  p[j].b <= req_max){
                        curr_max = Math.max(curr_max, p[j].b);
                    }
                }
                if(curr_max == req_max ){
                    System.out.println("Yes");
                    possible = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!possible)
            System.out.println("No");
            
        }

    }
}
```

But this will certainly fail for the following testcase. It will give "Yes" when it should have given "No", Because there is no continuous path of length **3**.

```
1
3 3
1 2
3 4
4 5
```

As suggested by **kcsquared**. I modified my code.

It runs correctly. I think Question setters had set weak test case for this question.

Comment: Is your question how to debug this code, or how to solve that problem? You've invented a testcase that the code doesn't work on; are you asking about why that particular test fails?

Comment: How do i solve this problem correctly. I could have gone with the answer they provided in Editorial. But it is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your test-case demonstrates, the error is that when adding new segments to extend the current segment, there's no test to check whether the new segment can reach the current segment or would leave a gap. To do so, compare the new segment's left end to your current segment's right end:

```java
for(int j = i + 1; j < N; j++){
    if(p[j].a <= curr_max &&  p[j].b <= req_max){
        curr_max = Math.max(curr_max, p[j].b);
    }
}
```